# Update duplicate rows except for one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named `simple_data` that has millions of mobile numbers in a column named `MSISDN`, but it contains duplicates.

All rows have a `FLAG` column set to zero.

I want to update all duplicate rows by setting `FLAG` value to `2` except one row.

```
CREATE TABLE `wt_simple_data` (
  `SIMPLEID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CAMPID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `MSISDN` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `FLAG` enum('0','1','2') DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '0 FOR NOT SENT, 1 FOR SENT',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SIMPLEID`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Some sample data:

```
SIMPLEID  CAMPID     MSISDN        FLAG    
 15        311      9874123411      0    
 16        311      9874123411      0    
 17        311      9874123411      0    
 18        311      9874123412      0    
 19        311      9874123412      0    
 20        311      9874123413      0    
 21        311      9874123413      0    
 22        311      9874123414      0
```

My desired result

```
SIMPLEID  CAMPID     MSISDN        FLAG    
 15        311      9874123411      0    
 16        311      9874123411      2    
 17        311      9874123411      2    
 18        311      9874123412      0    
 19        311      9874123412      2    
 20        311      9874123413      0    
 21        311      9874123413      2    
 22        311      9874123414      0
```

Comment: And you use all the databases that you have tagged?

Comment: yes i looking for logic in all database and i am having awareness in all database which i tagged

Comment: Don't just in case tag products not involved... Use ANSI SQL if it's a product independent question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may do with JOIN and keeping the first record as `0`

```
update 
wt_simple_data w1 
join ( 
  select 
   min(SIMPLEID) as SIMPLEID,
   CAMPID,
   MSISDN 
   from wt_simple_data 
   group by CAMPID,MSISDN 
)w2 
on w1.SIMPLEID > w2.SIMPLEID 
and w1.CAMPID = w2.CAMPID 
and w1.MSISDN = w2.MSISDN 
set w1.FLAG = '2'
```

Comment: When you do update on millions of records then unfortunately there is't any shortcut, it will consume some time. However having indexes may make it faster but it can not be super-fast. But yes the query should work.

Answer (score 0):

general SQL:

```
UPDATE wt_simple_data
SET flag='2'
WHERE simpleid IN (
    SELECT simpleid FROM wt_simple_data WHERE flag = '0'
    MINUS
    SELECT MIN(simpleid) FROM wt_simple_data WHERE flag = '0'
    GROUP BY msisdn
)
```

using analytical function:

```
UPDATE wt_simple_data
SET flag='2'
WHERE simpleid IN (
    SELECT simpleid
    FROM (
        SELECT MIN(simpleid) OVER (PARTITION BY msisdn) minsimpleid, simpleid
        FROM wt_simple_data
        WHERE flag = '0')
    WHERE minsimpleid <> simpleid
)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.Flag = 2
FROM wt_simple_data a
INNER JOIN (SELECT MIN(SIMPLEID) SIMPLEID, CAMPID, MISSION 
                     FROM wt_simple_data
         GROUP BY CAMPID, MISSION
                    ) ON a.CampId = b.CampId AND a.Mission = b.Mission AND a.SimpleId > b.SimpleId
```